# Shadow in 3d plot Matlab

Tags: matlab, 3d, shadow

I want to add the shadow/reflection of the trajectory to each side of my 3d plot **(2D perspective projection)**, something like the picture below:

[image]

```matlab
a = 1.;
b = 0.3;  
c = 0.3;

b1 = 0.008;
b2 = 0.008;
b3 = 0.002;

c1 = 0.004;
c2 = 0.0045;

eta = [50 20 20];
F = @(t,y) [a*y(1) - b1*y(1)*y(2)-b2*y(1)*y(3)- b3* y(1)*y(1) ; -b*y(2) + c1*y(1)*y(2); -c*y(3) + c2*y(1)*y(3)];
[t,y] = ode45(F,[0: (300/1000000): 300], eta);
plot3(y(:,1),y(:,2),y(:,3), 'color', 'blue','LineWidth',2)
grid on;
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess the simplest approach would be to plot lines on the plane of the axes. For instance, in your given example (I assumed `a = 0.3` as you did not specify `a`) `plot3` produces this figure:

[image: Original image without shadow]

Here is what you wanted to add:

```
hold on
plot3(0*y(:,1),y(:,2),y(:,3), 'color', 'k','LineWidth',1); % shadow on the Y-Z plane
plot3(y(:,1),0*y(:,2),y(:,3), 'color', 'k','LineWidth',1); % shadow on the X-Z plane
plot3(y(:,1),y(:,2),0*y(:,3), 'color', 'k','LineWidth',1); % shadow on the X-Y plane
```

which produces a graph like this:

[image: Figure with shadow]

FYI, you can also use `imagesc` to produce shadow for a surface like the example [in this page](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imagesc.html) which basically adds a 2D image of a 3D surface on the axes.

Comment: Thank you very much. a=1. but when I add these three lines I can see only the last plot and can not see all four plots together. am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @MathMath "hold on"?

Comment: Yes, as @wwweagle mentioned I forgot to add "hold on". It's added to the answer now